# Moving database with phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have a remote (website) version of a wordpress site and it's got more recent information than my local (computer) version.

I would like to move the data over to my local using phpMyAdmin, what is the best way to go about this?

Should I just export the entire database, import it and re-link my wordpress site to the "new" (more recent) database in the config file?

Answer (score 2):

I would do this so.

But this is probably not the most efficient way accomplishing this task.

There are several plugins out there, that may automate this. If anyone knows one, that is good, I would like to hear about it.

Plugins that look promising:

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xcloner-backup-and-restore/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/duplicator/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-migrate-db/

Find more at:

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/backup

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for me (although, to be honest I wasn't too attached to my local database, so if I lost it...)

```
From "online" version
Go to phpMyAdmin
Export SQL (Structure and data)
```

Then:

```
On "local" computer version
Write down the name of the database
Drop the database. 
Open the SQL file you exported.
Do a find and replace:
www.the-online-site-name.com
replace with:
localhost/local-site-name

Choose the wordpress database in phpMyAdmin.
Import the SQL
```